# Bayesian logistic regression likelihood

Tags: logistic, bayesian, likelihood

If we know that:

[image]

How should I calculate the likelihood? I arrived to the next expression:

[image]

But something must be wrong because when I do this numerically, if n is big this likelihood will tend to 0... Easily deductible

Comment: There is nothing wrong. For example, the probability of seeing any particular string of coin flips tends to zero as you increase the number of coins filpped.

Comment: In practice, you should compute the logarithm of the likelihood, or *loglikelihood*.  Then the numerical problems that you mention will go away.  Then you will find out that when you actually use the likelihood for something, the theoretical formulas mostly use the loglikelihood ...

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you would compute the logarithm of the likelihood, or *loglikelihood*.  Then the numerical problems you mention should disappear.  If the goal is to compute maximum likelihood estimates, then the loglikelihood is enough. Since $\log$ is a monotone increasing function, the likelihood and the loglikelihood is maximized at the same parameter values.

And then, if you want some indicator of the precision of those estimates, you will find that the hessian matrix of the loglikelihood at the estimate is useful, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information or [Theoretical motivation for using log-likelihood vs likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289190/theoretical-motivation-for-using-log-likelihood-vs-likelihood/289193#289193)

If you want to choose between different models, then AIC (Akaike Information Criteria) is a possibility. Look it up, the loglikelihood again ... And soon you will discover that using loglikelihood is not merely convenient, it does also has many theoretical advantages.