# Fisher Information | Second Derivative of Likelihood Vs Second Derivative of Log Likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information, likelihood

I watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m62I5_ow3O8&t=3m53s) on Fisher Information and it is mentioned that in Taylor series expansion of the likelihood function the second derivative is parabola which is not a good approximation and a better approximation is second derivative of log of likelihood function which is gaussian.

Question: Why gaussian (second derivative of log of likelihood) is a better approximation then parabola (second derivative of likelihood)?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289190/theoretical-motivation-for-using-log-likelihood-vs-likelihood